# Как добавить виджет в компоновку?

Tags: c++, qt

Помогите, пожалуйста, добавить текстовое поле внутрь окна w. Почему-то выходит создать два отдельных окна. Вот  мой код

mainclass.cpp

```
#include "mainclass.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

MainClass::MainClass(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    QVBoxLayout *QMTLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QTextEdit *TE = new QTextEdit;
    QMTLayout ->addWidget(TE);
    TE->setGeometry(0,0,600,600);
    TE->show();
    setLayout(QMTLayout);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainclass.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainClass w;

    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf-8"));
    w.resize(800, 600);
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon("C:\\Qt\\TexRed/TLeater.jpg"));
    w.setWindowTitle("Текстовый редактор");
    w.setFocus();

    QHBoxLayout *QMTLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QTextEdit *MainTextEdit = new QTextEdit;
    QMTLayout ->addWidget(MainTextEdit, 8);

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы виджеты отображались в окне а не как отдельное окно, им нужно задать родителя. Вот как правильно создавать виджеты (это делается внутри класса MainClass)

```
QHBoxLayout *QMTLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
QTextEdit *MainTextEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
QMTLayout ->addWidget(MainTextEdit, 8);
this->setLayout(QMTLayout);
```

А так же необходимо главному виджету окна установить Layout в который добавил виджет.